# woocommerce quantity field displayed not properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I create Product slider plugin for woocommerce. in my plugin i need to display quantity with add to cart button in product slide view. following code i added woocommerce_quantity_input() function to display quantity field within the div. but unexpectly quantity field display out of the div. how to fix this issue

```
$displayslide.='<div class="productcartsection">';  

$displayslide.="<form action=".esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() )." class='cart' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"; 

$displayslide.=woocommerce_quantity_input();    

$displayslide.='<button type="submit" class="button alt">Add Cart</button>';

$displayslide.="</form>";    

$displayslide.='</div>';
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: check the html of the page and see if you can get the reason?

Comment: html code added. @GiacomoM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that woocommerce_quantity_input echoes (output) the field by default.
When you want to add it to a string and then output, you need to pass the third value of it as false.
This is the function declaration on WC plugin:

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input( $args = array(), $product = null, $echo = true ) {
```

So you can change your code this way:

```
$displayslide .= woocommerce_quantity_input(array(), null, false);
```